# Mysterious slow HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I discovered one of the two 1TB HDDs on my Win7 Lenovo laptop is extremely slow.

My machine is a win7 lenovo laptop.  C: has a Samsung 1tb drive, it's working fine.  D: is a 1tb WD10SPCX -- it's working terribly.

AS SSD benchmark confirmed this:

[image]
[image]

Someone suggested S.M.A.R.T. might show the d: drive is dying.  But CrystalDiskInfo says the drive is perfectly healthy.

[image]

Windows says the drivers are up-to-date,  and I couldn't find any source of firmware update from the Western Digital home.

[image]
[image]

Afraid I'm running out of diagnostic ideas here.  What else could be broken or maladjusted here?   I note that windows says these are SCSI drives. They're not.  Checking online I see many forum posts complaining about this, but the answers suggest it's fine,  that a SATA controller shows as SCSI sometimes.

Comment: Your HDD performance is as expected.  Your **SSD** is supposed to be faster then your HDD

Comment: http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/3227/WDC-WD10SPCX-22HWST0 A third what your experiencing is within the realm of normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare apple and oranges. The Samsung 850 EVO is a SSD and the WD10SPCX is the Western Digital Blue, which is a traditional HDD.

And normal HDDs (with only 5400rpm) are significant slower compared to SSDs.

Everything is fine and expected.